# Rails _only_ rendering layout and not page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout

kind of have a weird problem cropping up here... whenever I define a layout, rails *only* renders the layout and forgets about the rest of the page. Any ideas as to what might cause this sort of behavior?

i.e. render 'page' will render the page, but render 'page', :layout => 'header' will *only* render the header, which can be seen below along with the controller.

Comment: Have you checked your log / server output for any exceptions?

Comment: Can you post a code sample of your controller and layout pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `<% yield %>` instead of `<%= yield %>`?  I've wasted a few hours on that typo, and the symptoms are the same as you're describing.